# Adjust top padding with fitsSystemWindows

Tags: android, padding, android-statusbar

I have a `RecyclerView` list below an `AppBarLayout`. The `AppBarLayout` has a height of `112dp` and the `RecyclerView` has a top padding of `116dp`. If I active `fitsSystemWindows` on the `AppBarLayout`, however, the `RecyclerView` doesn't move, leaving a wider padding space between the elements. Is there a way to dynamically remove the height of the status bar or measure the height of the `AppBarLayout` below the status bar? I currently have to manually subtract the known status bar height from the padding, but this seems to go against the point of `fitsSystemWindows`, which is to provide a future-proof way to interact with the system UI.

Edit to add: I am aware of methods of programatically changing the padding in `onCreate`/`onCreateView`, however I am hoping there is an XML way to define this basic, common layout specification. In the meantime, I am (unsuccessfully) trying out programmatic changes to the padding, and for lack of a declarative way to specify this, what is the most "accepted" way to do this in the activity/fragment class?

Comment: There is an attribute for it, named -> "?attr/actionBarSize" or "?android:attr/actionBarSize" which you can use to access AppBarLayout Default Height.